# How to set padding left right for dynamic cards in a row

Tags: html, css

I am developing a e-commerce website I have 3 Card layout sometimes if there is 2 card, I need to set padding left and right dynamically
I tried with

```
justify-content: space-between
```

but

```
|Card1|       |Card2|
```

I want something like this

```
|Card1|  |Card2|  |Card3|

|Card1|  |Card2|  |Card3|

|Card1|  |Card2|
```

Here is my code

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="cardEach>
  </div>
  <div class="cardEach>
  </div>
  <div class="cardEach>
  </div>
  <div class="cardEach>
  </div>
  <div class="cardEach>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.card{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.cardEach {
    width: 31.3%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All you needed to do was remove the justify content.

```css
.card {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
}

.cardEach {
    width: 31.3%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
    <body>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="cardEach">test</div>
            <div class="cardEach">test</div>
            <div class="cardEach">test</div>
            <div class="cardEach">test</div>
            <div class="cardEach">test</div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Hi @Ahmed  I did this but there is no padding between cards

Comment: @tinyVariant you have to clarify what you mean by that, as far as I can tell this achieves what you wanted, maybe draw something in paint by hand of what you want it to look like.

Answer (score 0):

Use `justify-content : start` instead. Click [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) to know more about `justify-content`.

```css
.card{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: start;
}
.cardEach {
    width: 31.3%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="cardEach">
    Card 1
  </div>
  <div class="cardEach">
    Card 2
  </div>
  <div class="cardEach">
    Card 3
  </div>
  <div class="cardEach">
    Card 1
  </div>
  <div class="cardEach">
    Card 2
  </div>
  <div class="cardEach">
    Card 3
  </div>
  <div class="cardEach">
    Card 1
  </div>
  <div class="cardEach">
    Card 2
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to manually add `padding` instead of `justify-content`, you can use `padding` on the CSS. Click [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding) to know more about `padding`.

```css
.card{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
}
.cardEach {
    width: 31.3%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="cardEach">
    Card 1
  </div>
  <div class="cardEach">
    Card 2
  </div>
  <div class="cardEach">
    Card 3
  </div>
  <div class="cardEach">
    Card 1
  </div>
  <div class="cardEach">
    Card 2
  </div>
  <div class="cardEach">
    Card 3
  </div>
  <div class="cardEach">
    Card 1
  </div>
  <div class="cardEach">
    Card 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi, @miftahulrespati I did this but There is no padding left and right

Comment: Honestly, I really don't understand what your question is. If you want to add padding on your `card`, just add `padding` on the css.

Comment: @tinyVariant there I add a second answer, is that what you mean about `padding`?

Answer (score 0):

Just use this one. complete solution for padding left-right for dynamic cards in a row.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <style>
      .card {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="cardEach">test</div>
      <div class="cardEach">test</div>
      <div class="cardEach">test</div>
      <div class="cardEach">test</div>
      <div class="cardEach">test</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```